# Evolute of a Catenary

Tags: geometry

[Ref of evolute of catenary](http://amatterofmind.org/Pierres_PDFs/EUROPEAN_ART/BOOK_I/6._RAPHAEL_SANZIO_THE_CATENARY_TRACTRIX_PRINCIPLE_OF_THE_TRANSFIGURATION.pdf)

Evolute of a Tractrix is a Catenary. What is the evolute of a Catenary?

Sketched by Leonardo DaVinci Page 3, Fig 2.

EDIT1:

and also on  Page 23, Fig 8.

[DaVinci_LastSupper](http://amatterofmind.org/Pierres_PDFs/EUROPEAN_ART/BOOK_I/1._LEONARDO_DA_VINCI_THE_LAST_SUPER_AND_THE_CATENARY_TRACTRIX.pdf)

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatenaryEvolute.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually disagree with the mathworld answer. If you take the simplest case ($a=1$), the catenary is $\alpha(t)=(t,\cosh t)$. The general formula for the evolute of a plane curve is
$$\beta(t) = \alpha(t) + \frac1{\kappa(t)}N(t),$$
where $N$ is the principal normal. For the catenary, we calculate that 
$$\kappa = \text{sech}^2t, N = (-\tanh t,\text{sech} t),$$
so $\beta(t) = (t-\sinh t\cosh t, 2\cosh t)$. Here's a sketch:

[image: Catenary Evolute]

Comment: Maybe lines $( x=0,y=0 )$ of the catenary can be also included for reference.